# JPA @OrderBy don't work in @ElementCollection

Tags: java, jpa, sql-order-by

Good day all.

A have a simple Entity that have @ElementCollection of Set inside.
The scheme of DB tables - therefore: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXZTB.png)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Dealer")
public class Dealer implements java.io.Serializable{
 private int id;
private Set<Integer> modelYears = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(0);
...
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @XmlTransient
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "DealerModelYear", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "DealerId"))
    @Column(name = "ModelYear")
    @OrderBy("ModelYear ASC")
    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name = "modelYear")
        public Set<Integer> getModelYears() {
        return this.modelYears;
    }

    public void setModelYears(Set<Integer> modelYears) {
        this.modelYears = modelYears;
    }
```

And here Don't work  @OrderBy("ModelYear ASC") - why>? it's must be implemented during SQL request to DB. (moreover in official documentation have similar example with Set )

Thank you in advance.

Comment: An `OrderBy` is to order elements by a field of the element. With a `Set` firstly there is no such ordering since its a Set, and secondly the element has no field! Does an "Integer" have a field "ModelYear"? Nope.

Comment: @Neil Stockton Ok, Does it mean that //OrderBy for  //ElementCollection  works only with //Embeddable types? And if we are wand sort it's acceptable to use TreeSet<Intager> implementation for Set<Intager>?>

Comment: `OrderBy` only makes sense with embeddables when using `ElementCollection`, yes. TreeSet is one way, as long as your JPA provider support setting the comparator when the set is instantiated.

Comment: @Neil Stockton, thanks for your support. now all clear.

Comment: @ElementCollection sory, changing implementation from private Set<Integer> modelYears = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(0); to private Set<Integer> modelYears = new TreeSet<Integer>(); doesn't help to sort resultedSet of data from db>? use Hibernate 3. Possible did you have idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the answer to this topic refer to comments of @Neil Stockton.
Additionaly don't forget to mark your collection with @Sort annotation, because hibernate during work transform the collections in own types (PersistentSet, or for @Sort marked - SortedPersistentSet).